# how to use twitter bootstrap with ASP.net Controls?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, controls

I am trying to learn how to use twitter bootstrap with ASP.Net Controls like DropDown and Buttons and all other asp controls?

Is it Possible to do something like this?

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/JeremyMorgan/archive/2012/09/18/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-on-an-asp.net-website.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the [Bootstrap documentation and samples for buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#buttons) for a visual display of the out-of-the-box Bootstrap button styles.

Reference the `bootstrap.css` file in your page or master page, like this:

```
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Note: You can reference the human-readable `bootstrap.css` file or the barely readable minified version called `bootstrap.min.css`, for deployment make sure to use the minified version.

---

You can then apply Bootstrap CSS class names to ASP.NET `Button` controls, like this:

```
<asp:Button id="Button1" 
            runat="server" 
            CssClass="btn btn-primary" 
            Text="Bootstrap Button" />
```

The concept can be applied to the other ASP.NET server controls as well.