# Bootstrap with ASP .NET controls

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

Is there a way to apply bootstrap classes to all my asp .net controls at a time.
Following is my menu control formatted using bootstrap.

I don't want to do this to all the menus in my application individually. Is there a way to commonly apply bootstrap theme to all the Menus in my application. I face this same problem with buttons, textboxes and other controls as well. It is difficult to format each control individually.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
                aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span><span
                    class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="Mycompanylink">My Company</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" RenderingMode="List"
                IncludeStyleBlock="false" StaticMenuStyle-CssClass="nav navbar-nav" 
                DynamicMenuStyle-CssClass="dropdown-menu" OnMenuItemClick="Menu1_MenuItemClick">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Home" Value="0"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Careers" Value="1"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="About Us" Value="2"></asp:MenuItem>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you tried by giving reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852563/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-with-asp-net-controls

Comment: Ya, Currently i am doing the same, defining cssClass for every control in my page, But assume that suddenly one day i have to change the  CssClass="btn btn-primary"  to  CssClass="btn btn-default" for all the buttons in my solution, it's very difficult through this approach, So i want all my buttons to refer to my custom style and that custom style should refer to bootstrap, so when i change   btn-primary to btn-default in my custom style, all the buttons in my solutions gets changed. Is there a way to do this.

Comment: I don't want to directly edit or refer to bootstrap css files for my controls, I need a custom css file which will act as a mediator between .net controls and bootstrap css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

Create ASP .NET Themes and define all your required control attributes in the skin files. Inside the theme I placed bootstrap.min.css and like a magic it started working. I am able to refer all the bootstrap classes in ASP .NET skin files.

So if i change **btn-primary** to **btn-default** in my skin file, it is reflecting for all the buttons in my solution.

Thank you all for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

As @NnN [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852563/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-with-asp-net-controls), you can apply Bootstrap to many of the ASP.NET controls in a project. What that answer does NOT point out is that there are also many controls that are totally unsuited for responsive design as they create their own tables. For example, a GridView creates its own table and is unsuitable for [RWD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design), so you would use a ListView instead.

Check the MSDN documentation for any particular control you are unsure about. Better still, just place a control on a test page and view the HTML source created in your browser. If you see any dynamically created table, stay away from it. In general, in RWD we never used fixed sizes; everything is based on percentages in a grid context.

**UPDATE**

Normally, you would create a custom.css stylesheet. You never need to touch the original Bootstrap CSS files. You simply override existing Bootstrap rules or create new style rules in your custom.css file. Per your question about not having to change your CSS manually for every control: you can avail of SASS variables as described [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/) (Note, this is version 4 of Bootstrap). This way you only ever need to change something once.